# Setting default editor language in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, microsoft-office-2007

I want to change my default editing language in word as English (India). It is not so possible to change the language setting in all users and all PCs manually.

Manually we can change the default language by going to Word options>> Language>> Add additional editing language>> Make it as default.

Is there any automation to do this?
Any solution like exporting and importing the registry, or running command to do this are ok for me

Found registry for office 2010 in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\LanguageResources
```

But for office 2007 didn't find in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\LanguageResources
```

How to track in office 2007?

Automation in MS Office is very useful thing to save the time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft documentation (see ref list below) the key you looked at for 2007 was correct.  Possibly you looked for the keys before the user had opened an office product and they were not written yet, or different office products were installed using different language settings.

As you mentioned the keys should be as follows for 2007:

- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\LanguageResources\EnabledLanguages
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\LanguageResources

The values you are looking for are:

- UILanguage
- HelpLanguage
- FollowSystemUI
- UIFallback (used when diff. lang. used on diff. deploy)

The data for these keys is the LCID which for EN-India is 4009(16393) *Hex(Dec)*

Another option is to use Group Policy.

1. Copy the 2007 Office system policy template files to your computer.
2. Under Computer Configuration or User Configuration in the console tree, right-click Administrative Templates.
3. Click Add/Remove Templates and then click Add.
4. In the Policy Templates dialog box, click the template that you want to add and then click Open.
5. After you add the templates that you want, click Close.
6. Open the Group Policy object (GPO) for which you want to set policy.
7. Double-click Computer Configuration or User Configuration and expand the tree under Administrative Templates.
8. Locate language-related policies in the Microsoft Office 2007 system\Language Settings node.
9. Select the languages that you want to use for each setting.
10. Save the GPO.

The following policies help you manage language settings in the 2007 Office system:

- **Display menus and dialog boxes in**   Located in the Display Language folder. Determines the language of the user interface.
- **Display help in**   Located in the Display Language folder. Determines the language of online Help. If this policy is not configured, the Help language uses the user interface language.
- **Enabled Editing Languages**   Located in the Editing Languages folder. Enables editing languages from the list of languages supported by Office.
- **Primary Editing Language**   Located in the Enabled Editing Languages folder. Specifies the language in which users work with Office applications and documents when more than one language version is available on the computer.

The above was obtained from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179091(v=office.12).aspx#section1  note that that page is specific to the office 2007 version, but if you go to the following site http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162397(v=office.12).aspx there is an option at the top of the webpage to view similar information for subsequent versions of office.

Comment: This solution (Editing registry) wont work. I did changes language setting. But registry not changed and also imported registry. Setting not applied. I dint check GPO as automation is needed for me and I am not in domain

Answer (score 0):

I think this will change your default to English(India) via VBA within Word 2007.

```
Sub test()
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.LanguageID = 16393
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.NoProofing = False
End Sub
```

Try it and then go to `review - set language` and see what is default